# How to use the strip() function efficiently

Tags: python

Can you please tell me why the strip() function does not work?

```
str1= 'aaaadfffdswefoijeowji'

def char_freq():
    for x in range (0, len(str1)):
        sub = str1[x]
        print 'the letter',str1[x],'appearence in the sentence=', str1.count(sub, 0,len(str1))
        str1.strip(str1[x])

def main():
    char_freq()

main()
```

Comment: -1 the strip() functions works, but your code does not express your intent correctly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.strip()` is working just fine, but strings are immutable. `str.strip()` **returns** the new stripped string:

```
>>> str1 = 'foofoof'
>>> str1.strip('f')
'oofoo'
>>> str1
'foofoof'
```

You are ignoring the return value. If you do store the altered string, however, your `for` loop will run into an `IndexError`, as the string will be shorter the next iteration:

```
>>> for x in range (0, len(str1)):
...     str1 = str1.strip(str1[x])
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

To count strings, *don't `str.strip()`*; that just removes characters from the start and end of a string, not in the middle. You could use `str.replace(character, '')` but that would be inefficient too; but combined with a `while` loop to avoid the `IndexError` problem that'd look like:

```
while str1:
    c = str1[0]
    print 'the letter {} appearence in the sentence={}'.format(c, str1.count(c))
    str1 = str1.replace(c, '')
```

Much easier would be to just use a [`collections.Counter()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

freq = Counter(str1)
for character, count in freq.most_common():
    print '{} appears {} times'.format(character, count)
```

Without a dedicated `Counter` object, you could use a dictionary to count characters instead:

```
freq = {}
for c in str1:
    if c not in freq:
        freq[c] = 0
    freq[c] += 1

for character, count in freq.items():
    print '{} appears {} times'.format(character, count)
```

where `freq` then holds character counts after the loop.

Comment: Oh ok, so how do i get rid of those unneeded chars?

Comment: Anything missing here? Or did you not mean to unaccept?

Comment: Everything is just fine , but i got banned from posting questions in the site because of 2 people who down voted my questions..
It seems a little absurd.
I dont know what to do....
I Can't really help other people because of my lack of knowledge..
I think this site is kind of suppressing new users..